Locale setting warnings when running Perl commands with Strawberry Perl
I am using Strawberry Perl to run Perl on Windows 10. The problem is: whenever I type a Perl command, it always shows warning messages like below:
command:
perl -v

result:
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
        (possibly more locale environment variables)
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the system default locale ("English_United States.1252").

This is perl 5, version 38, subversion 2 (v5.38.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2023, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at https://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

I tried to add the value en_US.UTF-8 to LANG and LC_ALL in system environment variables, but it didn't help.
Why is that and how to fix it?

Use MSWin locales, not *nix ones.

@choroba could you elaborate on MSWin locales? Is it module Win32::Locale in Perl? If it is, then using it in the script does not help.

The value en_US.UTF-8 is a *nix locale name. English_United States.1252 is a Windows one. See What is the Windows equivalent for en_US.UTF-8 locale? (at StackOverflow) for an explanation and details.

@choroba That works! Thanks for your help.
